# How to add customer Attribute inside custom tab section insted of "Account Information" in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, adminform, customer-attribute

I have created customer Attribute programmatically and need that attribute to outside of "Account information" tab... means in custom tab.

[image]

I have tried with customer group.... ui component file as below

```
<fieldset name="custom_fields">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Fields</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="customer_blood_group">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Blood Group</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer_blood_group</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

but it's not working... any other way to sort out this issue ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try this https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-tab-in-admin-customer-edit-page-in-magento-2/

Comment: i have created custom tab... need to add customer attribute inside that

Comment: Hi @rakeshprajapati please check my updated answere

Comment: Hello @rakeshjesadiya your code is good but I need to customer attribute display in custom tab and there field drop-down can you help me this matter

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">CMS Page Hierarchy</label>
        </settings>
        <fieldset name="custom_fields">
                <field name="customer_blood_group" formElement="input">
                    <settings>
                        <label translate="true">Custome</label>
                        <dataType>number</dataType>
                        <visible>true</visible>
                        <dataScope>customer_blood_group</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

OR

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <fieldset name="test">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custome enable</item>
               <item name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">1</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <field name="enable">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                   <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer</item>
                   <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yes</item>
                       </item>
                       <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                           <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No</item>
                       </item>
                   </item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </field>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```